# Concave function but does not hold the Slater conditions

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I need to come up with a programming problem in standard from that is concave but DOES NOT satisfy the Slater condition. This is what I come up with but not sure...

$f(x) = -x^2$

$g(x): x<0 $

I knew it is concave function but with this constraint g(x) does it not hold at the Slater condition? Thank you for help

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please use proper formatting; for information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Slater condition requires that there is a point in the (relative) interior of the feasible set. If you want to negate the Slater condition, it is enough to make sure that the (relative) interior of the feasible set is empty.

For a simple example like yours, you should assume $x=0$. If you insist on inequality constraints, assume both $x\ge 0$ and $-x \ge 0$.

For a slightly more interesting example in $\mathbb{R}^2$, you may take $f(x,y) = -x^2-y^2$ under the constraint $y=x$ (or, more generally, $ay+bx=0$ for some $a,b \ne 0$).